# Distance from a point to a line segment using a custom distance function

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

**EDIT: I have solved the problem for my particular distance function using alternative ways however I think it's probably worth it to keep this question open as it would be interesting to find a more generalized formula for closest point in a line segment for any distance function. After all my, question still stands.**

I'm trying to find the distance from a line segment **AB** to a point **C** in 2D space. This is a pretty normal problem solved using the formula

[image]

On the numerator we have twice the area of the triangle **ABC** and on the denominator we have the distance **AB**.
Now this formula gives the distance from **C** to the point that is closest to the line that passes in **A** and **B**.
The way to solve this and to have the closest point only in the line segment is to simply limit the values to be between the distance from **C** to **A** and **B**, this way if the closest point is outside of the line segment we will instead get the distance from **C** to **A** or to **B**, whichever is closest.
This works obviously because **A** and **B** are the closest and farthest distances to **C**, at least when we consider the Euclidean distance.

My problem is what if I'm using a different distance function that isn't based just on the coordinates of the point so we might have a situation where the closest point is actually in the middle of the line segment. I can no longer limit the values to be between the distances to **A** and **B**.
This image should help see the problem.

[image]

I want to find the distance from **C** to the line segment **AB**. Obviously I had to adapt the previous formula to my distance function but that isn't a problem and I know it's working correctly.
In this example the actual closest point in the segment is **D**. It's closer than **A** and **B**. However it calculates that **E** is the closest. If this was in Euclidean distance I could just limit it to be between **A** and **B** but it's not an option here. Any ideas or hints about what to do?

Comment: If you want a useful answer, you need to be more specific about what you mean by "a different distance function". In general the answer will be that you can take the same approach, but you'll need a different formula for the distance from a point to a line, which you'll have to derive from the distance function. Depending on how complicated the distance function is, this derivation may require some calculus.

Comment: @Micah I see. I was vague because my distance function is quite complicated. I'm doing the same that I was doing in this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2966632) but now finding the distance from that funnel center to a line segment inside the funnel. Also as I mentioned I already changed the formula to get the distance between a point and line to my distance function, my problem is to limit that distance to be in the segment AB